# New custom field doesn't show in web layout and "Enable the new work item form" doesn't show on TFS 2018 Collection Settings

Tags: tfs-workitem

In TFS 2018, I am creating a custom template by using the Agile template as the base. I added a new field to the "Task" work item and updated the layout. In Process Template Editor when I use the Preview, it shows my new field. Uploaded the template to TFS 2018. Created a new project using the new template. I am able to see the new field in queries, but on web layout in TFS that custom field doesn't show up. I have checked things like read-only and hide empty settings. I can even import data into this new field using VSTS Sync Migrator and see it in queries. When I open the Task in web layout, it shows all the data other than the new field. When I open a new task to enter data, same thing, the custom field doesn't show.

Given that I am changing the web layout, I see some discussions about "Enable the new work item form" under Collection Settings. I am server admin, collection admin and project admin but "Enable the new work item form" doesn't show. I have tried clearing cache, restarting TFS services but no help. It seems that the new custom field will only display if I activate something.

I tried removing some other standard fields like "Description" from the task in my new Process template web layout for the task workitem and it keeps displaying them in the web layout on TFS. Another proof that the new layout is not taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I wasn't using the WebLayout tags in the XML file. I was using the Process Template editor which only updates the FORM elements which aren't used in TFS 2018. Had to add my elements to the weblayout section and all worked good.

Comment: Adding to your findings: The option "Enable the new work item form" is not available in TFS 2018 because it only supports the new form.